# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while using CoreAnimation

Tags: ios, core-graphics, exc-bad-access, uibezierpath, cakeyframeanimation

I use CoreAnimation to animate UIImageView (curve Bezier animation). Here`s my code:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationCubic;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

CGPoint endPoint = originalPosition;

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:star.layer.position];
[path addQuadCurveToPoint:endPoint controlPoint:CGPointMake(star.layer.position.x, endPoint.y)];

pathAnimation.path = path.CGPath;

[star.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"moveToScorebarAnimation"];
```

As a result, I get **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)** with stacktrace:

```
CoreGraphics`CG::Path::apply(void*, void (*)(void*, CGPathElementType, CGPoint const*)) const:
0x613c06:  pushl  %ebp
0x613c07:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x613c09:  subl   $24, %esp
0x613c0c:  movl   8(%ebp), %eax
0x613c0f:  movl   (%eax), %ecx
0x613c11:  movl   (%ecx), %eax
0x613c13:  movl   16(%ebp), %edx
0x613c16:  movl   %edx, 8(%esp)
0x613c1a:  movl   12(%ebp), %edx
0x613c1d:  movl   %edx, 4(%esp)
0x613c21:  movl   %ecx, (%esp)
0x613c24:  calll  *64(%eax)
0x613c27:  addl   $24, %esp
0x613c2a:  popl   %ebp
0x613c2b:  ret
```

I tried to use different manuals to do it, but app crashes the same way. Can't understand where`s my fault. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

P. S. Here's a similar [bug](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck/issues/221), but unfortunately it is solved just by removing animation.

P. P. S. Arc is enabled. Also, if I comment *pathAnimation.path = path.CGPath;* line, crash does not appear, as well as animation (what is not surprised :) ).

Comment: Are you using ARC in your project?

Comment: Can you tell us on which line the EXC_BAD_ACCESS is occurring? (Be sure to enable All Exception Breakpoints in Xcode).

Comment: Crash occurs on the last line (breakpoints and zombies are enabled)

Answer (score 1):

That error will be thrown when the object doesn't exist in memory. Make sure you initialization is proper way ?? make sure you initialize `Layer..etc..` ?

> Best way is use **BreakPoint** to find out where your application get crush ??

I'm not sure but it may be helpful for you.

Add your animation as

```
CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
group.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: pathAnimation,nil];
group.duration = 7.0;  //The total time of the animations, don't know if redundant
group.delegate = self;

[self.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"path"];
```

Comment: Crash occurs on this line: [star.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"moveToScorebarAnimation"]; Also I tried your one, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace CAKeyframeAnimation with CABasicAnimation:

```
 CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
 pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:star.layer.position];
 pathAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPoint];
 pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
 pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

Seems it's Apple bug

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You saved my day. Cheers. Happiiee Coding.:)