# Crash in a CAKeyframeAnimation for animating a view along a path

Tags: ios, core-animation, exc-bad-access

I have some code to animate a UIView: zoom it down while animating it along a path.

It crashes with the error below (reproducible: always):

```
CoreGraphics`CG::Path::apply(void*, void (*)(void*, CGPathElementType, CGPoint const*)) const:
0x1055c06:  pushl  %ebp
0x1055c07:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1055c09:  subl   $24, %esp
0x1055c0c:  movl   8(%ebp), %eax
0x1055c0f:  movl   (%eax), %ecx
0x1055c11:  movl   (%ecx), %eax
0x1055c13:  movl   16(%ebp), %edx
0x1055c16:  movl   %edx, 8(%esp)
0x1055c1a:  movl   12(%ebp), %edx
0x1055c1d:  movl   %edx, 4(%esp)
0x1055c21:  movl   %ecx, (%esp)
0x1055c24:  calll  *64(%eax)
0x1055c27:  addl   $24, %esp
0x1055c2a:  popl   %ebp
0x1055c2b:  ret
```

I *think* it comes from the method below (`pathAnimationWithStartPoint:`), as if I don't add the CAKeyframeAnimation returned by it, i.e., just:

```
[group setAnimations:@[ zoomAnimation ]];
```

instead of

```
[group setAnimations:@[ zoomAnimation, pathAnimation ]];
```

it runs without crashing.

```
- (CAKeyframeAnimation *) pathAnimationWithStartPoint:(CGPoint) startPoint {
    CGPoint endPoint = self.showApplicationTourButton.center;

    CGFloat xDistanceBetweenStartAndEndPoints = abs(startPoint.x - endPoint.x);
    CGFloat yOfHighestPointOfCurvePath = endPoint.y - 250;

    CGPoint controlPoint1 =  CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 1.0f / 3.0f * xDistanceBetweenStartAndEndPoints, yOfHighestPointOfCurvePath);
    CGPoint controlPoint2 = CGPointMake(startPoint.x + 2.0f / 3.0f * xDistanceBetweenStartAndEndPoints, yOfHighestPointOfCurvePath);

    CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, controlPoint1.x, controlPoint1.y, controlPoint2.x, controlPoint2.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);


    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
    CGPathRelease(curvedPath);



    pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
    pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;


    return pathAnimation;
}
```

Backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1a03, 0x01055c11 CoreGraphics`CG::Path::apply(void*, void (*)(void*, CGPathElementType, CGPoint const*)) const + 11, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x01055c11 CoreGraphics`CG::Path::apply(void*, void (*)(void*, CGPathElementType, CGPoint const*)) const + 11
    frame #1: 0x00f5d090 CoreGraphics`CGPathApply + 64
    frame #2: 0x01838c68 QuartzCore`CA::Render::Path::new_path(CGPath const*, bool) + 158
    frame #3: 0x018c3493 QuartzCore`-[CAKeyframeAnimation _setCARenderAnimation:layer:] + 176
    frame #4: 0x018c3b2c QuartzCore`-[CAKeyframeAnimation _copyRenderAnimationForLayer:] + 68
    frame #5: 0x018c6f12 QuartzCore`-[CAAnimationGroup _copyRenderAnimationForLayer:] + 241
    frame #6: 0x018df547 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_animations(CA::Transaction*, double (*)(CA::Layer*, double, void*), void (*)(CA::Layer*, CA::Render::Animation*, void*), void (*)(CA::Layer*, void**, void*), void*) + 641
    frame #7: 0x01855520 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_layer(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) + 94
    frame #8: 0x018d87fa QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 330
    frame #9: 0x018d877e QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 206
    frame #10: 0x01856667 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 1775
    frame #11: 0x01857227 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 395
    frame #12: 0x018f9b17 QuartzCore`+[CATransaction commit] + 52
    frame #13: 0x000399bf MyApp`-[HomeViewController catchTourScrollViewScreenshotViewAndAnimateItToButton](self=0x0b4e5210, _cmd=0x006f381a) + 1903 at HomeViewController.m:197
    frame #14: 0x0391f663 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    frame #15: 0x0003c383 MyApp`-[NSObject(self=0x0b4e5210, _cmd=0x006ef5ad, selector=0x006f381a) performSelectorIfRespondsToIt:] + 243 at NSObject+PerformSelectorIfRespondsToIt.m:22
    frame #16: 0x00042506 MyApp`__44-[TourViewController closeTourWithAnimation]_block_invoke268(.block_descriptor=0x0b6985a0, finished='\x01') + 86 at TourViewController.m:419
    frame #17: 0x01af0df6 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 223
    frame #18: 0x01ae3d66 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 237
    frame #19: 0x01ae3f04 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 68
    frame #20: 0x12b6ff28 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationStateAccessibility(SafeCategory) animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
    frame #21: 0x018df7d8 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 284
    frame #22: 0x03a90014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #23: 0x03a807d5 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 296
    frame #24: 0x03f3eaf5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1925
    frame #25: 0x03f3df44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #26: 0x03f3de1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #27: 0x044c67e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #28: 0x044c6668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #29: 0x01aa5ffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #30: 0x0000285d MyApp`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3f4) + 141 at main.m:16
    frame #31: 0x00002785 MyApp`start + 53
* thread #1: tid = 0x1a03, 0x01055c11 CoreGraphics`CG::Path::apply(void*, void (*)(void*, CGPathElementType, CGPoint const*)) const + 11, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x01055c11 CoreGraphics`CG::Path::apply(void*, void (*)(void*, CGPathElementType, CGPoint const*)) const + 11
    frame #1: 0x00f5d090 CoreGraphics`CGPathApply + 64
    frame #2: 0x01838c68 QuartzCore`CA::Render::Path::new_path(CGPath const*, bool) + 158
    frame #3: 0x018c3493 QuartzCore`-[CAKeyframeAnimation _setCARenderAnimation:layer:] + 176
    frame #4: 0x018c3b2c QuartzCore`-[CAKeyframeAnimation _copyRenderAnimationForLayer:] + 68
    frame #5: 0x018c6f12 QuartzCore`-[CAAnimationGroup _copyRenderAnimationForLayer:] + 241
    frame #6: 0x018df547 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_animations(CA::Transaction*, double (*)(CA::Layer*, double, void*), void (*)(CA::Layer*, CA::Render::Animation*, void*), void (*)(CA::Layer*, void**, void*), void*) + 641
    frame #7: 0x01855520 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_layer(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) + 94
    frame #8: 0x018d87fa QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 330
    frame #9: 0x018d877e QuartzCore`CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 206
    frame #10: 0x01856667 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 1775
    frame #11: 0x01857227 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 395
    frame #12: 0x018f9b17 QuartzCore`+[CATransaction commit] + 52
    frame #13: 0x000399bf MyApp`-[HomeViewController catchTourScrollViewScreenshotViewAndAnimateItToButton](self=0x0b4e5210, _cmd=0x006f381a) + 1903 at HomeViewController.m:197
    frame #14: 0x0391f663 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    frame #15: 0x0003c383 MyApp`-[NSObject(self=0x0b4e5210, _cmd=0x006ef5ad, selector=0x006f381a) performSelectorIfRespondsToIt:] + 243 at NSObject+PerformSelectorIfRespondsToIt.m:22
    frame #16: 0x00042506 MyApp`__44-[TourViewController closeTourWithAnimation]_block_invoke268(.block_descriptor=0x0b6985a0, finished='\x01') + 86 at TourViewController.m:419
    frame #17: 0x01af0df6 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 223
    frame #18: 0x01ae3d66 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 237
    frame #19: 0x01ae3f04 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 68
    frame #20: 0x12b6ff28 UIKit`-[UIViewAnimationStateAccessibility(SafeCategory) animationDidStop:finished:] + 66
    frame #21: 0x018df7d8 QuartzCore`CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 284
    frame #22: 0x03a90014 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #23: 0x03a807d5 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 296
    frame #24: 0x03f3eaf5 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1925
    frame #25: 0x03f3df44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    frame #26: 0x03f3de1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #27: 0x044c67e3 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 88
    frame #28: 0x044c6668 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #29: 0x01aa5ffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
    frame #30: 0x0000285d MyApp`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff3f4) + 141 at main.m:16
    frame #31: 0x00002785 MyApp`start + 53
```

Turning on NSZombie does not give any more useful debug information.

The same code used to work before upgrading to Xcode 4.6.3 (4H1503). To be noted: in the simulator, the animation sometimes was *paused* and clicking on it would resume it. This weird artifact was a sign that something was wrong but I didn't know it yet.

Did I miss something?
If this is a known bug, is there any workaround?

---

Some research notes:
A [similar question has been asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033507/exc-bad-access-while-using-coreanimation), but the accepted answer just "fix" the problem by changing the path animation to a linear translation.

My problem seems also very similar to the blog post here: http://www.blogosfera.co.uk/2013/08/exc_bad_access-while-using-coreanimation/

Comment: You only have one part in the path. Why do you need do pace it?

Comment: If `xDistanceBetweenStartAndEndPoints` is zero, you end up with a division by zero.  Does your setup guarantee that that will never happen?

Comment: @DaveDeLong Yes, external contraints guarantee that xDistanceBetweenStartAndEndPoints is not equal to zero. But I fail to see how the division by zero can occur. Wouldn't the operators precedence make it evaluated as `(1.0f / 3.0f) * xDistanceBetweenStartAndEndPoints`?

Comment: @Guillaume doh! you're right. pesky order of operations.

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't much of answer, but more of an attempt to give you a tool to find more clues.  Hopefully, someone with more clue than I will chime in.

- Turn on malloc stack logging.
- Reproduce the crash.
- Check the registers;  if $r0 or $r1 look like heap allocations, then get the malloc history of said address(s).

If the last event on either is a `FREE`, then the data buffer (or object) is being freed prematurely.  (see http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html for information on grabbing the malloc history).

Now, that may not actually help you *that* much even if it confirms that it is a premature deallocation.  What it will tell you, if so, is that it is a race condition.   Unfortunately, fixing it isn't really possible, but a workaround might be.  If you can figure out what object you control that might have allocated the prematurely `free()`d buffer, then you ought to be able to hold a strong reference to said object until the animation is fully completed.

And file a bug, attaching your crashing binary, please.

---

Also, turn on malloc scribble.  That'll ensure that deallocated memory is trashed immediately upon deallocation, which should make the crash happen as soon as it possibly can.

Comment: If it is a prematurely-deallocated object, then Instruments's Zombies template will help to find which object and what killed it.

Comment: @PeterHosey Only if it is really an Objective-C object, which it does not appear to be.  That won't work for malloc buffers (it only works for ObjC objects because a Zombie is effectively a proxy that logs on every method invocation).  The above is an attempt to correlate from the exploding buffer back to the prematurely deallocated object.

Comment: @bbum sorry for not replying earlier, I have things more critical to to take care first. I will submit the bug report as soon as I find some time to write it. I wanted to let you know that the same bug occurs when compiling with iOS 7 SDK.